# Android: action_send intent is not showing facebook

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent, send

I recently implemented the action-send intent to share a plain text. Facebook is installed and updated on my phone but only "Googlemail" and "Textmessage" are shown as options for sharing my text.

A short code snippet:

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("plain/text");
        intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, item.getTitle());
        intent.putExtra(
                android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                (item.getDescription());
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send..."));
```

Any suggestions what's wrong with my app?

Normally I would think that I dont have to implement the whole facebook sdk for my simple purpose?!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried with `intent.setType("image/jpeg");`? Just try with this type and see whether facebook is appears on chooser.

Comment: Oh yeah that gives me a lot other options including facebook. But now how can I insert my text there with an image as type? :/
PS: Guess that a kind of facebook-bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The MIME type to use is `text/plain`, not `plain/text`.

Comment: Fine now I can choose facebook but it doenst take any of the text I'm giving. Its working with WhatsApp and Co.
So is this now an unfixed facebook bug!?

Comment: @user1066006: That would be a question for Facebook. Assuming that you changed the MIME type, and assuming that `getTitle()` and `getDescription()` return non-null/non-empty values, what you have there seems OK.

Comment: Facebook have knowingly broken the filter contract for handling plain text. They want you to use their library, or use a URL in your text.